# Drawing a sprite from a spritesheet using XNA/Monogame

Tags: xna, sprite, monogame, sprite-sheet

I have a spritesheet with 2 sprites. Each sprite is 40x60. The total size of the image is 40x120.
It looks like this (the red line is part of the 1st sprite). I'll tell you in a second why I added that.

[image]

It seems that for some reason, when trying to draw the second sprite, it will always take the last line of the previous sprite. I have drawn that red line to illustrate that.

This is my code that draws the 2nd sprite:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 60, 40, 60); // Choose 2nd sprite
Vector2 pos = new Vector2(100, 100);
Vector2 origin = new Vector2(0, 0);

spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.Draw(mSpriteTexture, pos , rect, Color.White, 0.0f, origin, 6, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
spriteBatch.End();
```

And this is how it looks when I run the program:

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Note: For this example I'm using scale=6. I did this because it seems that when scale > 1 this problem will always happen. If scale = 1, it doesn't seem to happen all the time.

Comment: Have you tried using 61 at the Rectangle Y location when choosing the second sprite?

Comment: That doesn't work. Sprites overlap even more.

Comment: This problem is discussed here with some possible solutions: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/45764/xna-2d-spritesheet-drawing-rendering-problem

Comment: Did you try drawing with spriteBatch using destinationRectangle instead of scaling? Not guaranteeing a fix, just suggesting you try it to see if it works.

Comment: Monacraft, thanks for the link and for the suggestion. It provided some new ideas to try but it seems the author never found a solution. I had already tried most of them. Using PointClamp improved things a lot, but the problem still happened from time to time. I ended up adding some tile space and the problem is gone. Not the best solution but I fixed it for now.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Used SamplerState.PointClamp in my spriteBatch.Begin - call to fix it

It looks like this: (MonoGame 3.6 tho)

```
SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.NonPremultiplied, SamplerState.PointClamp, null, null, null, viewMatrix);
```